# Are there any established religions that explicitly support homosexuality?

Tags: abrahamic-religions

According to scripture [Judaism doesn't support gay marriage](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/how-do-christians-in-support-of-gay-marriage-interpret-anti-gay-bible-verses).  [Christianity is similar](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/how-do-christians-in-support-of-gay-marriage-interpret-anti-gay-bible-verses).  [Hindiusm talks about people born with out gender parts and therefore being 3rd gender](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/175/what-does-hinduism-say-about-third-gendered-people) but  [doesn't accept homosexuality](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/vedas-and-vedic-dharma-on-homosexuality).  [Buddhism says nothing about gay marriage or 3rd genders](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1886/what-is-the-attitude-toward-homosexuality-in-buddhism).  [Islam also is against homosexuality](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-does-the-quran-say-about-homosexuality).

I would like to refrain from talking about intersex people (people born without sexual organs or both male and female organs), because these are incredibly rare compared to actual homosexuality, and, as outlined in Hinduism, are considered to be an exception.  Chinese religions like Taoism and Confucianism say nothing about homosexuality.

Are there any religions that are both established (implying that they are relatively old, but still practiced) and explicitly support homosexuality?

Comment: [LGBT themes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_themes_in_mythology) are common in mythologies around the world. Can you clarify what you mean by "explicitly support homosexuality"?

Comment: @Ouroboros I would like a verse saying it is okay.  Stories are just that stories.  Hinduism is a great example of religion that actually explicitly has verses denying homosexuality despite having stories about it.

Comment: @Gibet mythologies are not always but I guess it could be a religion.  I read most of what you posted and I fail to see any mythologies listed there that would regarded as a religion today.  Also Hinduism similar to the mythologies you listed don't explicitly support gay marriage, but do talk about gods who were essentially gay.  This is not the same thing.  Hinduism would work under such requirement.

Comment: @Gibet if I am miss using the religions tag please do clarify.  I do not think I understand your point.  I have edited the question to only include still existing religions.

Answer (score 2):

In Greek Mythology, Zeus is said to have fallen in love with [Ganymede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(mythology)), a [kouros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kouros), per his beauty.  Zeus abducts him to serve as his cup bearer in Olympus.  The story has strong homosexual implications, but no one judged Zeus over it, which indicates there was no stigma.

[image]

Comment: Poseidon also snatches up Pelops to the same effect. Pindar, who seems to have invented that story (or its placement in myth) contrasts it with bad stories of the gods and their friends (i.e. Tantalus eating Pelops), indicating that he thought this was a good and appropriate action for Poseidon to take.

Answer (score 1):

Homosexuality was practiced by the ancient Greeks and Romans as well as ancient Sumerians, Babylonians and Assyrians. Although condemned in the the Bible, the Old testament mentions  that prostitutes and transvestites practiced their business in the Temple of Solomon at Jerusalem and dedicated the money they earned toward the temple's upkeep. The American Indians practiced homosexuality, calling men who behaved like women, squaw men, they wore women's clothes and did women's chores.

Comment: The Indian tribes isn't much of a religion but is certainly interesting.  Need a citation.  Unfortunately non of these religions are still around.

Comment: @William, Native American Animism is closer to religion than Buddhism as it has the concept of Great Spirits, e.g. [Wakan Taka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Spirit). Buddhism has no creator deities that gave a rulebook to mankind.

Comment: @Codosaur it states nothing of God so kinda up for you to decide.  It believes that nothing lasts forever therefore if there is a good he may or may not exist.

Comment: Can you add Wakan Taka to the answer maybe.  It seem to be the best answer by far.